# Django posts and responses

Tags: python, django, jquery

This is less a technical question, more a "am i doing this in the right way" question.

I have several models defined

```
class Style(models.Model):
    tag_xml = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="styles")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    uploaded = models.DateField()

class StyleMatch(models.Model):
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)
    item = models.ForeignKey(FashionItem)
```

they can't be populated via html forms simply due to the nature of the task, so in order to populate them I have a html page with jquery and lots of event functions and other javascript goodies. When the save button is clicked I call .ajax() and pass all of the collected variables

```
var saveRequest= $.ajax({
url: "/save_style/",  
type: "POST",        
data: "selection="+s+"&user="+user+"&src="+image_src,
dataType: "text"    
});
```

My save_style view then saves the values into the model

```
def save_style(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    selection = request.POST['selection'].rsplit("|")
    user = request.POST['user']
    src = request.POST['src']

    f = open(MEDIA_ROOT+src)
    image_file = File(f)

    u = User.objects.get(id=user)

    style = Style(tag_xml = "",
                  image = image_file,
                  user = u,
                  uploaded = date.today())
    style.save()

    for s in selection:
        if (s != ''):
            match = FashionItem.objects.get(id=s)
            styleMatch = StyleMatch(style = style,
                                    item = match)
            styleMatch.save()

    i = StyleMatch.objects.filter(style=style)
    items = FashionItem.objects.filter(id__in=i)

   return render_to_response('style_saved.html', dict(image=src, items=items, media_url = MEDIA_URL), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After doing this I really want to go to a success page and display the records I have just added to the model, however if I use `render_to_response` and pass back the model details I have to rebuild the entire page in javascript, it seems better to redirect to a new template, but if I use `HttpResponseRedirect` a) I can't pass back values and b) it doesn't appear to be redirecting quite right (I think because the post is originating from my javascript).

So finally my questions

1. Is this really how I should be doing this? The django doc doesn't
   really seem to cover these slightly more complicated areas, so I'm a
   little unsure.
2. Should I be using render_to_response or
   HttpResponseRedirect above? Or possibly a third option I don't know
   about.

Any suggestions appreciated.

FYI I know the code above is not ideal i.e. missing validation, comments ... etc, its simply been provided for demonstration purposes. Feel free to point out any serious issues though.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of your application, you probably shouldn't be building the entirety of your pages with JavaScript. However, since we're there already I've used the following solution with nice results:

Consider creating a template "fragment", as I call them. It's simply a bit of HTML that is designed to be a capsule for data transferred via AJAX. Do a render_to_response to this fragment, pass in your processed view data as variables, then retrieve this data via AJAX and use JavaScript to replace the HTML within a designated div element with the returned data.

There are some pitfalls with the above solution, such as styling and event handler attachment on the template fragment, but it should at least get you working. Just a tip in this regard, become familiar with jQuery's .on().

Comment: The page isn't entirely generated from javascript it is based on django html templates, there just happens to be a large amount of javascript associated with this particular page. In fact I have a result section which submits an ajax request and then uses render_to_response to nicely update the page without reloading. However now I want to save/commit these results, the actual saving is not a problem, I just want to redirect to a different page now instead of using render_to_response to rebuild the current page. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: You need not rebuild the entire page using the method I mentioned above. You can use a fragment of HTML such as <div>Your content and variables here</div> and just insert it into your existing document, without re-rendering the entire thing. So long as you fetch this fragment with AJAX, you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

> pass all of the collected variables

Why don't `$(form).serialize()`?

> saves the values into the model

Why don't use `django.forms.ModelForm` (or few of them)?

> doesn't appear to be redirecting quite right

Because redirects in AJAX are processed in AJAX call and do not affect opened page unless you process received data in JS somehow.

Also, you don't have any data validation and|or error reporting, that's bad. Actually, `ModelForm` should provide a huge help with that.

Comment: The OP stated that it's inappropriate to use HTML forms to create his model objects, so ModelForm isn't going to be of much use.

Comment: What I'm doing doesn't naturally lend itself to forms, tagging of images and user selection of dynamically built results. Maybe I should be using forms, but I don't know how I would do that for data that isn't nicely contained within text boxes or radio buttons. Thanks for the suggestion.